# Auto Import in Visual Studio Code for React-Native Development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

Is there an extension for **VS Code** that makes **Auto Import** for **React Native Components**?

For Example:

When I type `<View`, then it automatically suggest for `import { View } from 'react-native';`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out the [**Auto Import**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) plugin by *steoates* for VS Code

Comment: @Khemraj _"Works with TypeScript and TSX"_. So, should work with RN if you're writing TS.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I can autocomplete/import components from the project and from other libraries, but it doesn't work for the react-native lib components

Comment: it works for me but each time it imports something, cursor jumps to the bottom of the file making it unusable

Comment: For me, this one worked https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuclleaR.vscode-extension-auto-import. Also, change the **Autoimport: Files To Scan** setting to  `**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}`

Comment: @SumitShukla it doesn't work for any import? check if it has conflict with another plugin

Comment: @Maxwells.c which plugin?

Comment: try to disable all your plugins. Then, try to install https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuclleaR.vscode-extension-auto-import and change the settings i mentioned above